# kivy/python update label by a schedule

Tags: python, label, kivy, schedule

I try to update the text of an label continuously by using

```
Clock.schedule_interval.
```

In this example I got the following error message:

*NameError: global name 'radio_station' is not defined*

And I don't know why. Can some help me?

Thanks a lot.

kv-file:

```
<CtrlRadio>:
    radio_station: stationName
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            id: stationName
            text:"default text"
```

python file:

```
class CtrlRadio(Widget):
    radio_station = StringProperty()

    def print_info_to_display(self):
       radio_station.text = "Radio Station"

    # start scheduling - 500ms
    Clock.schedule_interval(print_info_to_display, 0.5)

class RadioApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return CtrlRadio()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    RadioApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
radio_station.text = "Radio Station"
```

Replace `radio_station` with `self.radio_station`.

Comment: Hi, thanks.I solved the problem in the meantime self.ids.radio_station.text